# DB Synchorinizing in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We Develop GTK Application under Linux with MySQL as back-end.
One of our client have branches in 4 cities & those was connected via VPN.
Each Branch have its own IBM server & separate Database for storing the Application Data.

Now the requirement is, those 4 Databases are merged to a Single Database without loss of records.

Is there any option for Synchronizing those DBs over VPN. Then that merged DB will be replicated to Branch servers.

Kindly help to solve this Issue.
Thank you in advance.